# Spring Boot with Spring HATEOAS Maven conflicts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

It seems when I add the dependency for the spring-hateoas

```
<groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.0.RELEASE</version>
```

The Class below is no longer available on the classpath

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

I have tried to exclude various dependencies for the spring-hateoas but the APP no longer runs.

Has anyone had any luck running spring-hateoas within spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no problem whatsoever. The `@RestController` annotation is still available and you shouldn't need to do any exclusion.

In case it helps, I'm currently using version 1.0.2 of Spring Boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

`spring-boot-starter-web` provides the `@RestController`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I don't define an explicit version for `spring-hateoas` in my `pom.xml`, but my build is pulling in `0.9.0.RELEASE`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As a side note, I can see from the Eclipse POM editor, that Spring HATEOAS is defining dependencies on Spring 3.2.7. However the `spring-boot-starter-parent` project manages the versions up to 4.0.3. Can you see what version of Spring you are getting? Have you perhaps not used the `spring-boot-parent` as a parent project?